# Calculate Daily and Weekly Overtime from Table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set up an Excel (2010) spreadsheet to calculate overtime for employees from a spreadsheet generated by the time clock. The report from the time clock gives total hours only. Overtime can be calculated by separating hours into regular hours and OT hours. Anything over 10 hours in a day counts as OT hours. Once you have hit 40 REGULAR hours (not including OT), all hours past that point are counted as OT. Then all OT is added up. If you never hit 40 regular hours, but still have daily OT, then daily OT is used.

I feel like this shouldn't be too terribly difficult. I've tried using some conditional formulas to calculate and break out the OT, but haven't been able to come up with anything that works in all cases and allows the process to be automated. I've included a link below to an example spreadsheet generated by the time clock. Is it possible to break out the OT the way I want without using VBA?

[Example Spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykre776dxhhqhp3/Test%20Time%20Report.xlsx)

Please let me know if you need any additional information. At least some ideas of where to start would be very welcome, or if there are other posts that address similar matters I could use to get going (I haven't been able to find any that quite work in this situation). Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking for code. But I'm not certain if it can be solved without VBA. I will try to throw some VBA at it, and will post what I am able to come up with as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a little brain challenge this morning so I decided to help you out. This is how I solved your problem.

[Turn on developer
   tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608625.aspx)

Open the Visual Basic Editor <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or

[image]

Insert a one standard *Module*

[image]

Copy and Paste the below code into that *Module*

```
Option Explicit

Sub OTHours()

    Sheets(2).Activate
    Range("G2:G" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    Dim e As Collection
    Set e = New Collection

    On Error GoTo RowHandler

    Dim i As Long, r As Range
    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range("C" & i)
        c.Add r.Row, r.Offset(0, -2) & "£" & r
    Next i

    For i = 1 To c.Count
        If i <> c.Count Then
            Dim j As Long
            j = c.Item(i)

            Dim m As Merged
            Set m = New Merged

            m.Name = Range("A" & c.Item(i))
            m.Dates = Range("C" & c.Item(i))

            Do Until j = c.Item(i + 1)
                m.Hours = m.Hours + Range("F" & j)
                m.Row = j
                j = j + 1
            Loop
        Else
            Dim k As Long
            k = c.Item(i)

            Set m = New Merged

            m.Name = Range("A" & c.Item(i))
            m.Dates = Range("C" & c.Item(i))

            Do Until IsEmpty(Range("A" & k))
                m.Hours = m.Hours + Range("F" & k)
                m.Row = k
                k = k + 1
            Loop
        End If
        e.Add m
    Next i

    For i = 1 To e.Count
        'Debug.Print e.Item(i).Name, e.Item(i).Dates, e.Item(i).Hours, e.Item(i).Row
        Range("G" & e.Item(i).Row) = IIf(e.Item(i).Hours - 10 > 0, e.Item(i).Hours - 10, vbNullString)
    Next i

    PrintOvertime e

    Exit Sub

RowHandler:
    Resume Next
End Sub


Private Sub PrintOvertime(e As Collection)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If StrComp(ws.Name, "Overtime Only", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ws.Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Overtime Only"
    Set ws = Sheets("Overtime Only")
    With ws
        Dim i As Long
        .Range("A1") = "Applicant Name"
        .Range("B1") = "Date"
        .Range("C1") = "OT hours"
        .Range("D1") = "Week Number"
        For i = 1 To e.Count
            If (e.Item(i).Hours - 10 > 0) Then
                .Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = e.Item(i).Name
                .Range("B" & .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = e.Item(i).Dates
                .Range("C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = e.Item(i).Hours - 10
            End If
        Next i
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    PrintWeekNum
End Sub

Private Sub PrintWeekNum()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Overtime Only")
    With ws
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim r As String
            r = .Range("B" & i).Text
            .Range("D" & i) = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Right(r, 4) & "-" & Left(r, 2) & "-" & Right(Left(r, 5), 2))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Now insert a *Class Module*

[image]

Copy and Paste the below code to it

```
Option Explicit

Public Name As String
Public Dates As Date
Public Hours As Double
Public Row As Long
```

Rename your *Class Module* to `Merged`

Note: you need to turn on the *Properties Window*, either click *View* on the menu bar then select *Properties Window* or hit <kbd>F4</kbd>

[image]

Select the *Class Module* and rename it from *Class1* to *Merged*

[image]

---

Go back to the spreadsheet view and select *Time Detail* Sheet

Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

[image]

or

select *Macros* on the Developer tab and hit <kbd>Run</kbd>

---

The **`OVERTIME`** results will be filled in to your *Time Details* Sheet column `G`

Also

There will be a new sheet added named **`Overtime Only`** which will have a table of all people who did extra hours. (and only people who earned Overtime)

The results will look like

**`Time Detail`**

[image]

**`Overtime Only`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great! The only problem is that it doesn't take into account weekly overtime for employees working over 40 hours. I took your code as a starting point, and modified it to take weekly overtime into account. I will post it below.

Comment: but now having the overtime in the OT hrs column you could add another column with week number and display it in a pivot table.

Comment: Well, right. If you look at my code, it still puts the OT hours in a separate OT hrs column, the same way yours does. I just modified the loop so that while it's calculating OT on a daily basis, it's also keeping track of the total hours for the individual, so once they hit 40 hours, it puts all the hours into the OT column. I also changed it to copy the OT hours into the OT column at the same time that it's going through the first loop, since it's calculating the OT hours right there, instead of separating that part in a different loop like in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer from @mehow and modified it a bit to take weekly overtime into account. I'm not sure if it's the cleanest or most efficient way to go about it, but it gets the job done.

I created an additional class module, "DlyHrs," which holds hrs for a single day for a single employee. Each person has a collection of these DlyHrs objects, so their total regular and OT hours for the week can be tracked.

Class Module "DlyHrs" -

```
Option Explicit

Public Day As Date
Public totHrs As Double
Public regHrs As Double
Public otHrs As Double
Public row As Long
```

I modified the Class Module "Merged" as so -

```
Option Explicit

Public Name As String
Public Hrs As Collection
Public regHrs As Double
Public otHrs As Double
Public totHrs As Double
```

So far, it seems to be working, and breaking out all daily and weekly overtime correctly. Here is the entire code for the macro -

```
Option Explicit

Sub OTHours()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Time Detail").Activate
Range("T2:T" & Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).ClearContents
Range("T1") = "OT"

Dim c As Collection
Set c = New Collection
Dim e As Collection
Set e = New Collection

On Error GoTo RowHandler

Dim i As Long, r As Range
For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set r = Range("H" & i)
    c.Add r.row, r.Offset(0, -7) & "£" & r
Next i

'store name of previous person to know when to add new person to collection
Dim prev As String
prev = vbNullString

For i = 1 To c.Count
    Dim j As Long
    j = c.Item(i)
    Dim curr As String
    curr = Range("A" & j)

    'if not dealing with a new person, add hours to existing person
    'rather than creating new person
    If curr = prev Then GoTo CurrentPerson
        Dim m As Merged
        Set m = New Merged
        m.Name = Range("A" & c.Item(i))
        Set m.Hrs = New Collection

    CurrentPerson:
        Dim curHrs As DlyHrs
        Set curHrs = New DlyHrs
        curHrs.Day = Range("H" & c.Item(i))

        If i <> c.Count Then
            'Add up hours column
            Do Until j = c.Item(i + 1)
                curHrs.totHrs = curHrs.totHrs + Range("K" & j)
                curHrs.row = j
                j = j + 1
            Loop
        Else
            Do Until IsEmpty(Range("A" & j))
                curHrs.totHrs = curHrs.totHrs + Range("K" & j)
                curHrs.row = j
                j = j + 1
            Loop
        End If

        'break out regular and OT hours and add to current person
        If m.regHrs = 40 Then 'all hrs to OT
            curHrs.otHrs = curHrs.totHrs
            m.totHrs = m.totHrs + curHrs.totHrs
            m.otHrs = m.otHrs + curHrs.totHrs
        ElseIf m.regHrs + curHrs.totHrs > 40 Then 'approaching 40
            curHrs.regHrs = 40 - m.regHrs
            curHrs.otHrs = curHrs.totHrs - curHrs.regHrs
            m.totHrs = m.totHrs + curHrs.totHrs
            m.regHrs = m.regHrs + curHrs.regHrs
            m.otHrs = m.otHrs + curHrs.otHrs
        ElseIf curHrs.totHrs > 10 Then 'not approaching 40, but daily ot
            curHrs.otHrs = curHrs.totHrs - 10
            curHrs.regHrs = curHrs.totHrs - curHrs.otHrs
            m.totHrs = m.totHrs + curHrs.totHrs
            m.regHrs = m.regHrs + curHrs.regHrs
            m.otHrs = m.otHrs + curHrs.otHrs
        Else 'no daily or weekly ot
            m.totHrs = m.totHrs + curHrs.totHrs
            m.regHrs = m.regHrs + curHrs.totHrs
        End If

        If curHrs.otHrs <> 0 Then
            Range("T" & curHrs.row) = curHrs.otHrs
        End If
        m.Hrs.Add curHrs

        Dim nextPerson As String
        nextPerson = Range("A" & j)

        'check if next name is a new person. if so, add current person to collection
        If curr <> nextPerson Then
            e.Add m
        End If
        prev = curr
Next i

Exit Sub

RowHandler:
Resume Next
End Sub
```